# Can a UIView be a UITextField Delegate

Tags: uiview, uitextfield, xcode4, sigabrt, uitextfielddelegate

I am getting a sigabrt error when I try to set the delegate of my UITextField to my UIView class. I have used the UITextFieldDelgate Protocal. here is my code

```
    nameField = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130, 40, 200, 30)];
    [nameField setDelegate:self];
    nameField.placeholder = @"<Game Name>";
    nameField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    [self addSubview:nameField];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are about to use `UITextField` in constructor, not `UILabel`. Replace your first string with the following:

```
nameField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130, 40, 200, 30)];
```